# How can I increment a counter in Vue JS from within a v-for loop without incurring an infinite update loop warning?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following simple v-for loop:

```
<div class="HolderRow" v-for="(row, index) in 9" :key="index">
   <Holder v-for="(row, index) in 11" :key="index" :holder1="increment()" />
</div>
```

On every render of "Holder", I wish to increment a counter by 1 and pass it as a prop to Holder. The increment method along with the incrementing data is as follows:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
      holder: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.holder = this.holder + 1;
      return this.holder;
    }
  },

  components: {
    Holder
  }
```

But, the problem is I get the following warning from Vue:

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

Is there any way to implement this without incurring such a warning/error?

Thanks

Comment: see `:holder1="index1+index2"` instead of a function, also you use `row` and `index` in nested loops....bad practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works (not sure if there is any other way):

```
<div class="HolderRow" v-for="(row, rowindex) in 9" :key="rowindex">
    <Holder
        v-for="(holder, holderindex) in 11"
        :key="holderindex"
        :holder="holder + (11 * rowindex)"
    />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove brackets of increment.

Should be `:holder1="increment"`

If you use brackets, increment function will be called before event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

First issue is you are using the same variable names in your loops, I would suggest using an alternate naming scheme. Then instead of mutating `holder` in a function it looks like you just want an index so you could do `index1*9+index2`

```
<div class="HolderRow" v-for="(row1, index1) in 9" :key="index1">
   <Holder v-for="(row2, index2) in 11" :key="index2" :holder1="index1*9+index2" />
</div>
```

Comment: I have 9 rows and 11 holders per row and I want to allocate a holder number to each holder the last should be 99 - the other way of doing this I could think of would either be incrementing in the child and emitting a custom function back up to update the state, or using a global state counter and use action/mutation pattern?